# What is this window logo like white shade on my laptop screen?

Tags: laptop, display

I have a window logo like curvy large white shade on my laptop screen. It was not there a month ago. Can anyone tell the reason of it being there? I have turned the background color to black to make it prominent. The laptop is an Acer Aspire E1-571.

Is there any reason to worry about it?

[image]

And here is a sample of what the shade looks like in the middle of the screen:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like a [screen burn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_persistence) to me.

I assume you had a wallpaper with the curvy Windows logo where the white shade is now.
It can take as little as only a few weeks for this kind of ghosting to set in, especially if the screen displays a certain image constantly.

Use a screen saver to prevent (further) [screen burn-in/image retention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_persistence).

You can often get rid of the image by using an anti-screen burn-in software or website but some damage can be permanent. These programs work by displaying or cycling white in fullscreen mode for a period of time.